# Отцентрировать Text Input (kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

мой python

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    # We create a dictionary of all our possible methods to call, along with keys
    def command_dict(self):
        return {

        }

    def process_command(self):
        # comand_key save comand
        command_key = self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text
        print(command_key)
        # We then use that key in the command built in 'get_method' because it is a dict
        # then we store it into a variable for later use
        called_command = self.command_dict().get(command_key, 'default')

        try:
            # The variable is a method, so by adding we can call it by simple adding your typical () to the end of it.
            called_command()

        except TypeError:
            # However we use an exception clause to catch in case people enter a key that doesn't exist
            self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text = 'you input: ' + command_key



class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Мой kivy

```
<MainWindow>:
    TextInput:
        id: fetch_key_and_process_command
        multiline: False
        size: 400, 150
        size_hint: None, None
        on_text_validate: root.process_command()
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу отцентровать `TextInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string('''
<MainWindow>:
    TextInput:
        id: fetch_key_and_process_command
        multiline: False
        size: 400, 150
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
''')


class MainWindow(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


MainApp().run()
```

---

```
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string('''
<MainWindow>:
    TextInput:
        id: fetch_key_and_process_command
        multiline: False
        size: 400, 150
        size_hint: None, None
''')


class MainWindow(AnchorLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


MainApp().run()
```

---

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string('''
<MainWindow>:
    Widget:

    TextInput:
        id: fetch_key_and_process_command
        multiline: False
        size: 400, 150
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

    Widget:
''')


class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


MainApp().run()
```